# Theme calling page.php instead of home.php

Tags: theme-development

I'm trying to help someone troublesheet a custom theme they made. The blog is set to display posts on the homepage, but the homepage should be custom from the rest of the site. The theme has a home.php set up with the customization.

When we change to the theme, home.php isn't loaded. I printed a debug_backtrace() and see that it's actually calling page.php instead of home.php. According to the template hierarchy, page.php should be being called since I've not set a static page as the homepage.

What else can I check to see why it's calling page.php instead of home.php?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `front-page.php` as your homepage template. So just rename `home.php` to `front-page.php` and it should work.

Comment: I just tried that, and it doesn't seem to affect anything. It looks front-page.php is only called for static pages, which we're not using for a homepage.

Comment: That seems strange, both not working. Is it possible that some code in your theme changes what template is loaded? I've many sites using front-page.php with frontpage settings on "Your latest posts".